# Openshift V3 Wordpress on free account - not enough storage

Tags: wordpress, openshift, storage

I host a Wordpress site on my Openshift 2 free account and need to migrate to 3 before 30th September before V2 is switched off. I have tried to create a wordpress site following this blog - https://blog.openshift.com/migrating-wordpress-openshift-3/ but have hit a road block --

I add a sql database but cant make it smaller than 1 Gb. I then can't add persistent storage because it says I am using my storage limit. Therefore I can't have themes, plugins, images etc in persistent storage.

Am I missing something or is it no longer possible to host Wordpress on an Openshift free account?

Thansks!

Answer (score 3):

The blog post uses a procedure which requires two separate persistent volumes, one for the database and one for Wordpress. To use a single persistent volume shared between the two is a bit more complicated and involves running both the database and Wordpress in the same pod. This can't easily be done through the web console.

In principal, if using the command line, you would start by using a command similar to:

```
oc new-app php~https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress \ 
mysql --group=php+mysql -e MYSQL_USER=wordpress -e \ 
MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

and then go on to attach a different sub directory of the one persistent volume to each application in the pod.

So technically it can probably be done, but a bit more fiddly to setup.

Do be aware that the Starter tier is not intended for sites which need to be running all the time. Applications will be subject to resource hibernation as explained in:

- https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html